# adjustable trapezoidal waveform

Tags: analog, circuit-design, waveform

I would like to buid a trapezoidal (waveform) with the following specs :
rise time : 10ns
VTop : 1V
tTop: 40ns
fall time: 15ns
Linearity is important

Frequency max : 10kHz 
Load is has a very high impedance (Op amp input)

I was planning to make a sawtooth first and then clip off the tops. (diodes to have different rise and fall times)
But  I would like to make the rise and fall time adjustable.

so, I would appreciate if someone could help me to find a more elegant and simple approach?

Comment: I think I understand what you're doing here. It sounds like you want to create your own waveform using electronic components. Things like this aren't impossible but they require some thinking. I would first consider the [Fourier Series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeries.html). Once you find the appropriate Fourier Series for your waveform that you wish to make, try to translate it with components of a circuit. If you figured this out, it would be really interesting as I honestly don't know a lot about waveform circuits other than oscillators and multivibrators.

Comment: All times must have tolerances if freq does not matter and a Voltage, load  included in spec

Comment: I added load and frequency @TonyEErocketscientist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Quick suggestions:

Does linearity matter?  If so, spec. it.

If you compute derivative and create those pulses, then a true integrator OA will result in your signal after initialization.

Consider a Howland Current Source, use cascaded 1-shot to set the current level with an analog switch to a preset voltage.

Plan B based on limited specs.

[image]

Comment: Linearity is quite important, frankly I do not understand the first proposition. Do you mean calculate the derivative and translate that into a equivalent pulse souce which will eventually be integrated back to a triangular waveform. I  I will look into howland current sources.

Comment: you got it, an OA integrator with a 3 level pulse with variable levels DAC, pot or other  dV/dt=I/C  100V/us,0,-67V/us

Comment: You can switch Current, voltage, capacitance or Resistance over 1/3rd V target range for good linearity. Analog switches may work to switch passive parts or voltages

Comment: I figured out a clever way http://tinyurl.com/y9lg8vrr

Comment: very clever indeed! need some time to process how it actually works.

Comment: RRIO OA with 2.6Vcc on the dual Op Amp. with pot set to ~1/3 of 5.00V logic level for offset adjust to 0V. Sim has a slider to right 1.7 nominal that I added.